# How to strip only specific parts of a list element in Python

Tags: python

So lets say i have a list, where one element contains an 'hour-minute-second-tagnumber', like this:

```
mylist = ['10 30 12 TTH-312', '10 38 45 ZHE-968', '11 25 54 KAP-116']
```

How do I make *this* of an element: `'103012 TTH-312'`?

Can I .strip only specific parts of an element somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the number of `replace` to 2.

```
[x.replace(' ','', 2) for x in mylist]
```

Output

```
['103012 TTH-312', '103845 ZHE-968', '112554 KAP-116']
```

If you are trying to do a loop:

```
adatok = ['10 30 12 TTH-312', '10 38 45 ZHE-968', '11 25 54 KAP-116']
for i in adatok: 
    i = i.replace(' ','', 2) 
    print(i)
```

Comment: Hey do you know why I would get the TypeError "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"? my code is:
'for i in adatok:
    oszlop = i.split(" ")
    oszlop[i].replace(' ','', 2)
    print(i)'

Comment: updated the answer.  your `split` turns the string into a list which is causing your problem.  You can skip that part.

Answer (score 1):

Using a list comprehension along with `re.sub` we can try:

```py
mylist = ['10 30 12 TTH-312', '10 38 45 ZHE-968', '11 25 54 KAP-116']
mylist = [re.sub(r'(\d+) (\d+) (\d+) (.*)', r'\1\2\3 \4', x) for x in mylist]
print(mylist)  # ['103012 TTH-312', '103845 ZHE-968', '112554 KAP-116']
```